# Can react hooks provide hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

This can probably be verified by a simple experiment.  I was wondering if I can have a hook provide new hooks.  For example given the following subscription manager

```
export interface SubscriptionManager<T = any> {
  /**
   *
   * @param fn function to call when notified.  It can be passed some data
   * @returns unsubscribe callback.
   */
  subscribe(fn: (data: T) => void): () => void;
  /**
   * Notify subscribers
   * @param data optionally pass data to the subscribers.
   */
  notify(data?: T): void;
}

/**
 * This hook provides a simple subscription semantic to React components.
 */
export function useSubscription<T = any>(): SubscriptionManager<T> {
  const subscribersRef = useRef<((data: T) => void)[]>([]);
  function subscribe(fn: (data: T) => void) {
    subscribersRef.current.push(fn);
    return () => {
      subscribersRef.current = subscribersRef.current.filter(
        (subscription) => !Object.is(subscription, fn)
      );
    };
  }
  function notify(data: T) {
    subscribersRef.current.forEach((fn) => fn(data));
  }
  return { subscribe, notify };
}
```

I want to generate a hook `useSubcriptionEffect(fn)` that prevents having  to write boiler plate code like this

```
useEffect(() => subscribe(fn), []);
```

The [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) only talk about "calls" but not "creation"

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow your question, as asked, against the supplied code snippet. The `useSubcriptionEffect` isn't returning any custom hooks, it's just returning an object, which is valid (*i.e. think what `useMemo`, `useCallback`, `useState`, `useReducer`, etc... all do*). ***EDIT*** Ok, I see now what you are asking... you want  to abstract away the necessary `useEffect` hook call.

Comment: Basically tried to do something like this.  

  function useSubscribeEffect(fn: (data: T) => void) {
    useEffect(() => subscribe(fn), []);
  }

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do [the experiment](https://github.com/trajano/react-hooks-tests/pull/1/commits/65fd71e52e37937cae13b4de6982b17a533574b6) to confirm if it works and it appears to, but it looks weird because of the name and how it is generated, since most hooks are `import`ed

The code is

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { SubscriptionManager } from "./SubscriptionManager";
/**
 * This hook provides a simple subscription semantic to React components.
 */
export function useSubscription<T = any>(): SubscriptionManager<T> {
  const subscribersRef = useRef<((data: T) => void)[]>([]);
  function subscribe(fn: (data: T) => void) {
    subscribersRef.current.push(fn);
    return () => {
      subscribersRef.current = subscribersRef.current.filter(
        (subscription) => !Object.is(subscription, fn)
      );
    };
  }
  function notify(data: T) {
    subscribersRef.current.forEach((fn) => fn(data));
  }
  function useSubscribeEffect(fn: (data: T) => void) {
    useEffect(() => subscribe(fn), []);
  }
  return { subscribe, notify, useSubscribeEffect };
}
```

The test appears to work

```
  it("should notify with clicks using generated hook", async () => {
    const callback = jest.fn();
    const MyContext = createContext<SubscriptionManager>({} as SubscriptionManager);
    function MyContextProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
      const { subscribe, notify, useSubscribeEffect } = useSubscription();
      return <MyContext.Provider value={{ subscribe, notify, useSubscribeEffect }}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
    }
    function MyComponent() {
      const { useSubscribeEffect, notify } = useContext(MyContext);
      function onClick() {
        notify();
      }
      useSubscribeEffect(callback);
      return (<div data-testid="test" onClick={onClick}>abc</div>);
    }
    const { getByTestId } = render(<MyContextProvider><MyComponent /></MyContextProvider>)
    const element = getByTestId("test");
    expect(element.textContent).toEqual("abc");
    await waitFor(() => expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(0));
    element.click();
    await waitFor(() => expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1));
    element.click();
    await waitFor(() => expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(2));
  })
```

Code is in https://github.com/trajano/react-hooks-tests/tree/useSubscribeEffect still trying to see if the naming makes sense before I merge it in.

Comment: I just want to know why would you need that, instead of a global store approach like mobx, or remx?

Comment: because I don't know what those technologies you are saying are about.